# Check complete overlap in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am able to check if two geometries are intersecting or overlapping through:

```
 if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
```

Is there any method available that tell me if one geometry completely overlaps with another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`contains`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#aa8b6f77d99ae0f657198184d4059bd85) is what you're looking for:

> Test for if geometry is contained in another

In your case, just write:

```
if a.geometry().contains(b.geometry()):
```

Comment: perfectly worked. can i use this for dot also

Comment: Yes, this should work for points also ([source](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a7fa96d0f125c10b0c2dedfb69d815cb6)).